# qml use element id in another file

Tags: qml

I have 3 files:

mainWindow.qml

```
       Rectangle{
            id: container

        Services{
            id: loger
        }
        ...//there is element code
 }
```

CategoryDelegate.qml

```
Item {
    id: delegate
...//there is element code
}
```

and MovieDialog.qml

```
Rectangle {
        id: movieDialog
...//there is element code
}
```

I need to use Services function in moviedialog and categorydelegate. From category delegate i can use it

```
Item {
    id: delegate

property string type: container.loger.getMovie(1)
//this code works well
}
```

But from moviedialog i cannot accept it!

```
Rectangle {
        id: movieDialog

property string type: container.loger.getMovie(1)
//this will not work
}
```

And i get error: "TypeError: Cannot call method 'getMovie' of undefined".

How can i fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In general that depends on the relation of your QML files.
You can access the ID of parent files directly, but not child files.

example:

```
// Parent.qml
Item {
  id: parent1

  // has NO access to child1 id, you have to define your own id in this file (child2)
  // you can also use the same id again (child1) if you want

  Child {
    id: child2
    // has access to the parent1 id
  }
}

// Child.qml
Item {
  id: child1
  // has access to the parent1 id if only included into Parent.qml
}
```

I also noticed in your example you've changed IDs, that is not possible, an ID is always unique in the current context, so instead of `container.loger.getMovie(1)` your should only use `loger.getMovie(1)`. If you need access to a child from outside of the file you need to define an property alias, e.g:

```
property alias log : loger
```

in your Rectangle (parent Item in the file, so you can access it from outside). This will actually create a public property of type `Services` in your case, so you can access it like any other property from outside of the file or wherever you need to.

I hope that helps with your problem.